# Does the Automatic away-status in Google Talk not function as it's supposed to?

Tags: google-talk

Using Google Talk on Android 2.2 on a Motorola Droid. Under settings I have the box for Automatic away-status checked. My assumption is that this would set my status to away when the screen is off as it states: *Set status to away when the screen is turned off*

However, this isn't the case. I've confirmed by walking over to a co-workers desk and it still shows me as available. I have Gmail closed on my desktop and it stays as available for ever, it doesn't just take some time to update.

Any ideas if this is a bug or is there a workaround? At the moment I'm just signing myself out when I remember to.

Comment: Would love to add a google-talk tag, but can't with my rep.

Comment: Added the tag for you

Comment: I also just realized I have this setting enabled too....  But I'm always logged in gmail, so I haven't a clue if I ever go "away" or idle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although some have reported it as a bug, apparently the *away status* only appears [after 10 minutes of idle time](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=167016fa81b074f3&hl=en) (defined as no use and the screen shutting off).

Comment: I guess it would help if I put my phone down for more than 10 minutes! Thanks.

Comment: probably good advice for all of us! Those  WinMo7 ads hit too close to home... [although, seriously, I'm not using my phone for a long time because the interface is crap, but because the interface is _good_. ]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately without actually testing these scenarios I cannot provide a definite answer but I can confirm that the feature works.

1. It may take time before Gmail or Google Talk are updated with your "away" status.
2. The feature may not work on lock screen activation... but on idle time. Personally this would be a smarter way of doing it. Just because I've locked my phone doesn't mean I'm away. On the other hand if I haven't used the phone for more than 5 minutes then mark me as away/inactive.

Best thing I can recommend is you play around with these two scenarios above. Lock the phone and monitor your status on someone else's computer. If you find something interesting post the results back :)